# sbt 0.13.0 JLine incompatibility detected

Tags: osx-lion, sbt

I have a problem with starting a play 2.2.0 app on my mac with mountain lion and java 7:

```
[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class jline.Terminal, but interface was expected
at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101)
at jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:159)
at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.ansiSupported(ConsoleLogger.scala:85)
at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.<init>(ConsoleLogger.scala:79)
at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.<clinit>(ConsoleLogger.scala)
at sbt.GlobalLogging$.initial(GlobalLogging.scala:40)
at sbt.StandardMain$.initialGlobalLogging(Main.scala:54)
at sbt.StandardMain$.initialState(Main.scala:60)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: JLine incompatibility detected.  Check that the sbt launcher is version 0.13.x or later.
at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.ansiSupported(ConsoleLogger.scala:96)
at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.<init>(ConsoleLogger.scala:79)
at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.<clinit>(ConsoleLogger.scala)
at sbt.GlobalLogging$.initial(GlobalLogging.scala:40)
at sbt.StandardMain$.initialGlobalLogging(Main.scala:54)
at sbt.StandardMain$.initialState(Main.scala:60)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)

Error during sbt execution: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: JLine incompatibility     detected.  Check that the sbt launcher is version 0.13.x or later.
```

It's not really linked to play since I got the same error when I start directly sbt in that directory.
So I tried a couple of things:

- removed all sbt related stuff from my home dir and tried to use the sbt script from https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/blob/master/sbt -> same problem
- removed all jars from my ivy repo dir and started again sbt -> same problem
- downloaded a sbt launcher directly (version 0.13.0) -> same problem
- tried with java 6 -> same problem
- tried to debug sbt to figure out what's wrong but all I found out was that jline does not recognize that it should use a UnixTerminal (which I got working by setting systemProperties) but then again -> same error

It's somehow related to some strange linking I think because the class version for the terminal which should be used seems to be old. At least this is what the jvm is complaining about.

I tried it on a virtual box with ubuntu which worked fine so I think my system is a mess or I did something completely wrong.

Someone any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you start the JVM with verbose class loading enabled (`-verbose:class`), that might help troubleshoot where the offending JLine classes are coming from. Perhaps you have a JLine jar in one of your JVM extension directories, probably `~/Library/Java/Extensions` or `/System/Library/Java/Extensions`.

Comment: u were right. but i was so sure that i already had inspected these directories. damn, somehow a version 1.0 jline jar found its way into /System/Library/Java/Extensions. thx m8

Comment: I cannot find jline related jars (or probably they its called somehow differently) in the folders you mentioned. Any other ideas?

Comment: kirhgoff: Did you start the JVM with verbose class loading enabled (`-verbose:class`), to show you where the offending JLine classes are coming from?

Answer (score 16):

I had same problem. My project is using SBT 0.13

Turned out I need to upgrade SBT Launcher to 0.13 version as well.

Comment: an ugly solution, though. Because why would then SBT need to download it's 0.13.0 version? If it can't use it? And the error reason is non-obvious.

Comment: @VasyaNovikov I agree. This problem was bugging me for months.

Comment: upgrading sbt, which for me was installed with brew solved this: `brew update; brew upgrade sbt`

Comment: its almost always better to have a localized `./sbt` script and a `./sbt-launch.jar` for these reasons, rather than relying on a system-wide sbt instance - especially as you get different production applications on different versions of sbt which is a real world issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also happen if you use an SBT launcher from 0.12 in an SBT 0.13 project, as suggested in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating SBT version to 0.13. Just download the sbt tar file and change the path in your .bash_profile file. Try again running sbt command in the project directory. That should fix the issue.