# Executing a camel blueprint with ActiveMQ as "Local Camel Context (without test)"

Tags: java, jboss, apache-camel, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

I'm new with Jboss Fuse and Jboss development Studio. And I have to develop a route to Fuse ESB using the ActiveMQ Endpoints.

I could execute and test the [Demo](http://wei-meilin.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/jboss-fusea-mq-easy-way-to-achieve.html) and the previous demos.

However, When I try to execute the more [complex route](http://wei-meilin.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/jboss-fusea-mq-easy-way-to-achieve_24.html) as "Local Camel Context (without test)" I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class jline.Terminal, but interface was expected
    at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.TerminalFactory.init(TerminalFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.TerminalFactory.getTerminal(TerminalFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.ConsoleFactory.doStart(ConsoleFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.ConsoleFactory$1.run(ConsoleFactory.java:98)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.JaasHelper.doAs(JaasHelper.java:67)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.ConsoleFactory.start(ConsoleFactory.java:96)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.ConsoleFactory.registerCommandProcessor(ConsoleFactory.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:297)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe$Listener.invokeMethods(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:573)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe$Listener.bind(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:555)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.bind(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:450)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.bind(ReferenceRecipe.java:164)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.retrack(ReferenceRecipe.java:132)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.updateListeners(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:442)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceRecipe.java:111)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:676)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:374)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:261)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceWrapper.java:106)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class jline.Terminal, but interface was expected
    at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.TerminalFactory.init(TerminalFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.TerminalFactory.getTerminal(TerminalFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.ConsoleFactory.doStart(ConsoleFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.ConsoleFactory$1.run(ConsoleFactory.java:98)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.JaasHelper.doAs(JaasHelper.java:67)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.ConsoleFactory.start(ConsoleFactory.java:96)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.ConsoleFactory.registerCommandProcessor(ConsoleFactory.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:297)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe$Listener.invokeMethods(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:573)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe$Listener.bind(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:555)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.bind(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:450)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.bind(ReferenceRecipe.java:164)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.retrack(ReferenceRecipe.java:132)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.updateListeners(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:442)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceRecipe.java:111)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:676)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:374)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:261)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceWrapper.java:106)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: actually, I could manage this problem by changing the fabric8 version.

Answer (score 0):

Check if SBT and SBT Launcher use the same version, see [sbt 0.13.0 JLine incompatibility detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466950/sbt-0-13-0-jline-incompatibility-detected).

If you use Maven as build tool, you may test this as follows:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Or, in a Karaf console, check the features with:

```
features:list
```